Ubuntu 24 autoinstaller works in VM but fails in hardware
I'm working on making an autoinstallation in an industrial PC. I manually installed Ubuntu and then retrieved the following autoinstall YAML file from /var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data:
#cloud-config
# See the autoinstall documentation at:
# https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/reference/autoinstall-reference.html
autoinstall:
  apt:
    disable_components: []
    fallback: offline-install
    geoip: true
    mirror-selection:
      primary:
      - country-mirror
      - arches: &id001
        - amd64
        - i386
        uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
      - arches: &id002
        - s390x
        - arm64
        - armhf
        - powerpc
        - ppc64el
        - riscv64
        uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
    preserve_sources_list: false
    security:
    - arches: *id001
      uri: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
    - arches: *id002
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  codecs:
    install: false
  drivers:
    install: false
  identity:
    hostname: asdasd
    password: $6$n5GGJGo5V//T7UzY$o7N1WW6cg4aWgfTcI7hrEyq9pmRgXtyhYwX5ZCS9awCxL4LfFrdF8AylRu5WcXjP/8E/GgSZ6pK8./F6uA.on/
    realname: asdasd
    username: asdasd
  kernel:
    package: linux-generic
  keyboard:
    layout: latam
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  network:
    ethernets: {}
    version: 2
  oem:
    install: auto
  source:
    id: ubuntu-server
    search_drivers: false
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      serial: SanDisk_SD9SB8W128G_21476B802930
      wwn: '0x5001b448b74d56fa'
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      id: disk-sda
      type: disk
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 1048576
      path: /dev/sda1
      id: partition-0
      type: partition
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 2147483648
      wipe: superblock
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2097152
      path: /dev/sda2
      id: partition-1
      type: partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      id: format-0
      type: format
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 125884694528
      wipe: superblock
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2149580800
      path: /dev/sda3
      id: partition-2
      type: partition
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
      type: lvm_volgroup
    - name: ubuntu-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 62939725824B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
      id: lvm_partition-0
      type: lvm_partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      id: format-1
      type: format
    - path: /
      device: format-1
      id: mount-1
      type: mount
    - path: /boot
      device: format-0
      id: mount-0
      type: mount
  updates: security
  version: 1

I've tried to reuse it in user-data, but I'm getting errors like the following:
autoinstall config did not mount root

I've also tried leaving the storage section free, to let it use LVM by default, but I'm getting the following error with grub installation:
grub-install: warning: Cannot set EFI variable Boot0000.

grub-install: warning: efivarfs_set_variable: writing to fd 8 failed: failed: Input/output error.

grub-install: warning: _efi_set_variable_mode: ops->set_variable() failed: Input/output error.

grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Input/Output error.

